# Need a help on this. Makefile is already there after ./configure command. But is is not running. This is when instralling Kannel

Tags: make

this is what I have tried. ./configure file run perfectly fine and libxml2-2.7.2 also installed perfectly. When running make file gets this error

```
thushantha@thushantha-VirtualBox:~/lankacom/kannel/gateway-1.4.4 $ make
Makefile:337: .depend: No such file or directory
yacc -d -p ws_yy_ wmlscript/wsgram.y && mv y.tab.c wmlscript/wsgram.c
/bin/bash: yacc: command not found
make: *** [wmlscript/wsgram.c] Error 127
```

Comment: It says that `yacc: command not found`. You might need to install the `bison` package. The requirements section at [kannel.org](http://www.kannel.org/overview.shtml) mentions GNU Bison.

Answer (score 3):

The error says `yacc: command not found`. You need to install the `bison` package which contains the program `yacc` in it. The requirements section at [kannel.org](http://www.kannel.org/overview.shtml) mentions GNU Bison.